# QGIS expression in Python @project_basename

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to modify a plugin and I want to change a line to use a qgis expression rather than python code
Currently the line is

```
BTC_Prj_Number = QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope(project).variable('BTC_Prj_Number') # Get the project number from the project variables
```

The QGIS expression I would like to use instead is

```
array_get(string_to_array( @project_basename,'-') ,0)
```

Which would mean I can use the project name rather than a variable to set  the BTC_Prj_Number.

I have tried the code below which looks about right but doesn't work.

```
BTC_Prj_Number = QgsExpression("array_get(  string_to_array( @project_basename,'-') ,0)").evaluate()
```

I get the error below, which I think means my expression generates "none"

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

I think the issue is with using **@project_basename** as the line below evaluates ok

```
QgsExpression("array_get(  string_to_array( 'iam hippo-1234','-') ,0)").evaluate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the right context to the evaluation. Try:

```
from qgis.core import (
    QgsExpression, QgsExpressionContext, QgsExpressionContextUtils, QgsProject
)

...

project_scope = QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope(QgsProject.instance())
expression_context = QgsExpressionContext([project_scope])
expression = QgsExpression("array_get(string_to_array(@project_basename, '-'), 0)")
BTC_Prj_Number = expression.evaluate()
```

Comment: I get the error "NameError: name 'QgsExpressionContext' is not defined"

Comment: You need to import the classes you need, see my edit.